# rPi with two video signals

Tags: video, archlinux

Is it possible to configure rPi B+ to drive simultaneusly two indpendent video signals (with arch or yocto linux), one over LVDS connector with touch screen feedback (to onboard serial port pins - for example 14" LCD screen) and other at full HD quality via HDMI (non touch, for example 65" TV)?

Comment: If you're asking about the LVDS/serial touch setup *and* the possibility for dual heads, you have two separate questions and should ask about the former independently.  This way someone who knows the answer to one but not the other will not be put off from answering.

Comment: @goldilocks, I KNOW LVDS/serial touch works, my question is, if I can drive second independent video signal via HDMI at the same time. And how is my question regarded as duplicate, if my question was issued before the [http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26995/multiple-display-screens] (Multiple Display Screens)?

Comment: As per the answer there (nb., the OP just added a comment with a confirmed case of the piTFT used simultaneous with the HDMI), the answer is yes. That question was actually asked two days ago; but duplicates don't as a rule have to be subsequent. It depends on the judgement of the person who notices the correspondence; that one is more general if they both boil down to "Can I do this or not?". This makes it more useful for people looking for that general question/answer. Note that questions closed as dupes aren't deleted and are intended to act as "signposts" leading to the canonical instance.

Comment: If you get this working and/or feel you have something to add, please add an answer there.