# Is it possible to have separate settings for composite and HDMI video?

Tags: hdmi, video, composite-video

For example, I want to output a 320x240 resolution to a composite monitor if no HDMI connection is found. Otherwise, output to HDMI as usual.

Is this possible? Can I edit something in config.txt or somewhere else? Can you use if-statements in config.txt?

Comment: If you are using the X server for a GUI, I'm pretty sure the answer is **yes**.  You can dynamically adjust the resolution w/ `xset` at any point; for what you want to do, you'd have to write some kind of short script to detect which output is in play.

Comment: I do not have an answer to your question. My Pi detects if hdmi is connected at boot and if not defaults to PAL. `tvservice -s` will show state e.g. `state 0x80001 [PAL 4:3], 720x576 @ 50.00Hz, interlaced`. I do not know if the default size can be changed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is possible, config.txt is read by the bootloader with very limited resources. But please look at this posting - it gives you a good suggestion on how to do this using a GPIO-based VGA adapter: [Multiple Display Screens](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26995/multiple-display-screens)

Comment: Unfortunately, using the GPIO pins isn't an option for me. Also, I don't need to use these screens simultaneously--it's an either/or situation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way you could do this with built in functionality.  The bootloader loads config.txt when the system starts, and once the system is up, that's it.

You could write a python/bash/ruby/whatever script that will swap out your config.txt config for a different one and restart the system.  This of course assumes that restarting the system is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

well... if you use either the composite or hdmi monitor (with useful `tvservice -n`-output) and the right one is already connected at the boot time (hotplugging won't change anything because the config.txt is read once at boot) you can probably use the `[EDID=*]`-filter in the config.txt!

please have a look at the real good [Raspberry Pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/) for the [config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md):
at the end there is a section about the filters (also the `[EDID=*]`-filter), and then you have to sort out your desired configurations for your hdmi monitor... the `[all]`-settings will be for the composite.

if you are not using always he same hdmi monitor you have to try multiple `[EDID=*]`-filters.