# How to make an external monitor working while lcd display is connected?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, hdmi, display

I have a touchscreen lcd display connected to Raspberry PI 2. Everything works fine: os is booting etc.

If I connect an external monitor via hdmi, I get some output on the monitor and some output logs on the display (probably the same), then the GUI is loaded on the display, not on the external monitor.

The last relevant log on monitor is:

```
 led pin not set, exiting.
```

However, the display works.

---

How can I switch between displays? If possible, I'd like to choose between:

- having one active display output (choose between connected displays: hdmi or lcd)
- displaying same thing on both outputs

I'd prefer using command line to switch between these. Is it possible?

---

Relevant output:

```
$ xrandr | grep "^[[:alpha:]]"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 480 x 320, current 480 x 320, maximum 480 x 320
default connected 480x320+0+0 0mm x 0mm
```

---

#### Almost found the solution

Since `tvservice -s` shows us that my raspberry detects my HDMI monitor, I inspired [from this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=91764#p650226) and did the following:

1. Edited the `/etc/modules` file and commented (`#`) the lines regarding the LCD screen. In my case they were the last three lines:

   ```
   #flexfb  width=320  height=480  regwidth=16 init=-1,0xb0,0x0,-1,0x11,-2,250,-1,0x3A,0x55,-1,0xC2,0x44,-1,0xC5,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,-1,0xE0,0x0F,0x1F,0x1C,0x0C,0x0F,0x08,0x48,0x98,0x37,0x0A,0x13,0x04,0x11,0x0D,0x00,-1,0xE1,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x24,0x20,0x00,-1,0xE2,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x24,0x20,0x00,-1,0x36,0x28,-1,0x11,-1,0x29,-3
   #fbtft_device debug=3 rotate=90 name=flexfb speed=16000000 gpios=reset:25,dc:24
   #ads7846_device model=7846 cs=1 gpio_pendown=17  keep_vref_on=1 swap_xy=1 pressure_max=255 x_plate_ohms=60 x_min=200 x_max=3900 y_min=200 y_max=3900
   ```
2. Added the following in `/etc/rc.local`, before `exit 0`:

   ```
   ################################################
   # HDMI / LCD
   #################################################
   echo "is it HDMI or DMT?" > /home/pi/tft.log
   /usr/bin/tvservice -s >> /home/pi/tft.log
   if (/usr/bin/tvservice -s | /bin/egrep 'HDMI|DVI') ; then
       echo "HDMI / DVI screen" >> /home/pi/tft.log
   else
       echo "switch on PiTFT" >> /home/pi/tft.log
       modprobe flexfb  width=320  height=480  regwidth=16 init=-1,0xb0,0x0,-1,0x11,-2,250,-1,0x3A,0x55,-1,0xC2,0x44,-1,0xC5,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,-1,0xE0,0x0F,0x1F,0x1C,0x0C,0x0F,0x08,0x48,0x98,0x37,0x0A,0x13,0x04,0x11,0x0D,0x00,-1,0xE1,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x24,0x20,0x00,-1,0xE2,0x0F,0x32,0x2E,0x0B,0x0D,0x05,0x47,0x75,0x37,0x06,0x10,0x03,0x24,0x20,0x00,-1,0x36,0x28,-1,0x11,-1,0x29,-3
       modprobe fbtft_device debug=3 rotate=90 name=flexfb speed=16000000 gpios=reset:25,dc:24
       modprobe ads7846_device model=7846 cs=1 gpio_pendown=17  keep_vref_on=1 swap_xy=1 pressure_max=255 x_plate_ohms=60 x_min=200 x_max=3900 y_min=200 y_max=3900
       startx
   fi
   ```
3. Reboot

Now when the HDMI monitor is:

- connected, the LCD remains white and the monitor is used, *but* it cannot start the GUI. However, I can access the TTYs (by pressing CTRL + ALT + F1). If I write `startx` it shows me **`no screens found error`** (maybe you have some suggestions here, I think that's why the GUI is not started)
- not connected, the LCD is used and GUI starts on it normally which is fine.

So, how can I make the GUI work on the HDMI monitor as well? Who says *do not start GUI but allow TTYs*?

Comment: Edit in the output of `xrandr | grep "^[[:alpha:]]"` with both screens attached; you'll have to run that from a GUI terminal, not the plain console.

Comment: @goldilocks I added the output using my little lcd display... :-)

Comment: @goldilocks Should I add the HDMI monitor manually, like [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/441075/148451)?

Comment: @goldilocks If I write `tvservice -s` my HDMI monitor is detected.

Comment: @goldilocks I think I'm almost there. [This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=91764#p650226) helped me a lot. From what I understand, it checks on boot if the monitor is connected and if so does nothing (I think here I have to do something), otherwise it activates the LCD display. The problem is now that `startx` outputs `fatal server error: no screen found`. I have terminal tty access on the hdmi monitor. Do you know how to activate the monitor (maybe using `modprobe`?)?

Comment: @goldilocks Confirming the LCD display works when HDMI is not connected. :D So, I have to make the HDMI monitor work with GUI (`startx`). That's the only thing which remained unsolved.

Comment: Does the HDMI work for that *without* the LCD attached?

Comment: @goldilocks With the current configuration I don't think so, because `tvservice -s` will detect it -- it will only allow me to enter in tty1 (CTRL + ALT + F1).

Comment: Did you install a special kernel or OS image to make the LCD work?  How is it attached?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26943/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-goldilocks).