# Can the official 7" touch display be used at the same time as an hdmi monitor?

Tags: hdmi, display, touchscreen

I am making a project where I want a monitor to host a webpage and the touchscreen will control an app I made that dynamically changes things on the webpage. Is the pi (pi3, mod. b) capable of powering both of these displays at once?

Edit: Found an answer that looks like it solved my issue: [Multiple Display Screens](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26995/multiple-display-screens?rq=1)

Comment: @Thomas Ha, no. I have searched and found a similar question, but not dealing with this particular setup.

Comment: Related: [mirrored 7" to HDMI on Win10IoT](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53203/win10-iot-raspberry-pi-3-w-7-display-and-hdmi-mirrored-screens)

Comment: Yeah, if you could try, that would be awesome. I don't know how no one has done this yet. I also wonder if there are different limitations between w10iot and jessie with the dual mons

Comment: Also related: [We can use the 7" with HDMI together](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54050/we-can-use-the-raspberry-pi-touchscreen-with-the-hdmi-together)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yeah, there is just no one that has tried it yet I suppose.

Comment: Edit: Looks like it will work: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26995/multiple-display-screens?rq=1

Comment: At least [not out of the box](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54303/what-happens-when-i-have-the-official-7-display-and-connect-a-monitor-via-hdmi/54304#54304)

Comment: @ThomasWeller nice write up man. Very interesting. I appreciate you taking the time to do this.

Comment: You're welcome. You made me interested. I could have imagined a few nice use cases, like using the touch pad as a keyboard and the HDMI as display. Basically the cheap version of http://store.artlebedev.com/for-programmers/objects/optimus-popularis/

Comment: @ThomasWeller or a large nintendo ds lol