# What happens when I have the official 7" display and connect a monitor via HDMI?

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, display

I own the [official 7" touch display](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/the-eagerly-awaited-raspberry-pi-display/) for the Raspberry Pi. I also own a HDMI monitor and I wonder what happens when both are connected to the Pi.

I am using Raspbian Jessie and the Pi 2B, if that matters.

Comment: Is there a command we can run to swap displays without rebooting? Maybe an alias that could modify the /boot/config.txt and add / remove the display_default_lcd=0 and reload a profile so you can swap between the touch and the HDMI screen at will, without a reboot?

Comment: Hmm, if you change something on the boot partition, I guess it needs a reboot. Unfortunately I'm not an expert in this area and what I gave as an answer almost exceeds my knowledge about displays on Raspbian. Please delete this question, since it's not an answer to the original problem. It was meant as a comment but yeah, I know, you can't comment yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following setup:

- official 7" touch display connected via the internal connector (not USB)
- a 1280x1024 VGA monitor connected via an HDMI-VGA adapter cable

the following happens:

- the Raspberry boots
- the 7" touch display is the main display
- the VGA monitor does not go to sleep
- the VGA monitor remains black

I have then tried the following to check if the HDMI monitor can display something:

- `sudo apt-get install fbi` to install the frame buffer image viewer
- `ls /dev/fb*` but that gives only one frame buffer device, which is `/dev/fb0`
- `fbi -T 0` appears on the 7" touch display
- `fbi -T 1` also appears on the 7" touch display

I then checked whether the VGA via HDMI monitor will be recognized as a frame buffer device in order to exclude the possibility that an HDMI monitor is never recognized as a valid FBI device:

- shutdown
- disconnect the 7" touch display
- re-power the Pi

The result is the following:

- the Raspberry boots
- the HDMI monitor is the main display
- the 7" touch display is black
- `ls /dev/fb*` but that gives only one frame buffer device, which is `/dev/fb0`
- `fbi -T 0` appears on the HDMI monitor
- `fbi -T 1` gives "the operation is not allowed"

### Conclusion

With minimum of effort (as described before),

- you can technically connect the 7" and the HDMI at the same time without breaking something (given a strong enough power supply, the one used for testing has 3.0A and I had WLAN, mouse and keyboard connected)
- you can't use both displays at the same time