# Is it possible to have two display panel

Tags: hardware, kernel, android

I am trying to build a customized Android device with the following capabilities:

- have two display panels
- display mode A: two panel showing differently, so together they merge to one big screen. One app will run at one time, and span to both screens
- display mode B: two panel showing the same content
- be able to switch between the two display modes during runtime (without restarting system or apk)

There are [instructions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26995/multiple-display-screens)
 how to achieve dual monitor display on Linux with X, however it's not available on Android.

Could someone shed some light on how to achieve the above feature? My most experience is in Linux, not Android, so I would appreciate if someone could give direction where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Display Screens](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26995/multiple-display-screens)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What about [this](https://boundarydevices.com/android-lollipop-dual-display-imx6/) ?